# Need help on trigger

Tags: trigger

We have two object say A and B. 
A has a lookup on B. 
A has two text field Type and year.
B has one text field Type and year
I want to populate the lookup field of A by matching Type and Year field of A with type and Year field of B. Trigger code should be bulkified. Need help, its urgent. Thank you

Comment: can you be more specific with what you've tried and where are you struck? Otherwise I don't anyone would be interested in writing code for you.

Comment: Hi sai, i m not able to query based on multiple condition with code bulkified. Just eg. Select Id, name from objectB where date = DateA and type = typeA. You can give the algo that is also fine

Comment: Shivdeep -- This community always likes to see the poster demonstrating code samples of what they tried and where they are stuck. Pleas of 'Need help, it is urgent' do not elicit community assistance where no work on your part has been shown

Comment: For a similar example to what Sai is suggesting, take a look at this question... http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9646/soql-query-help-using-specific-combinations-of-two-variables-that-also-appear-in

Answer (score 0):

Although you can do implement literally what you asked for, the better way is to create a third field on the objects which will be concatenation of type and year fields (if needed, you can also have them as unique/external Ids). This field can be populated using workflow. And your trigger and any other code can do the comparison using this new field.

Note: you also use a formula field for the third field if you're ok with some drawbacks, like this field not being indexed or potential of using this field as external Ids for data migrations.

Answer (score -1):

Best approach is to keep the bulkified logic out of the trigger and put it in a class. Use the trigger events to call the class and you already know, you can put different operations into different methods based on your needs.